# Show that $X$ must be degenerate at $n$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For $X$ which is an integer-valued random variable

$$\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-(k-1))] = \begin{cases}
    k!\ {n \choose k},& \text{if } k \in \mathbb{N}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$.

which can be rewritten as

$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{X!}{(X-k)!}\bigg] = \begin{cases}
    k!\ {n \choose k},& \text{if } k \in \mathbb{N}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$.

Though it was not mentioned, but $n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } n \geq k$ can be taken.

Show that X must be degenerate at n.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: We have to show that X is a degenerate distribution.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: See the headline of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k=1$, we get $E(X)=n$. For $k=2$ we get $E(X(X-1))=n(n-1)$ so $E(X^2)=n^2$. But this implies that the variance is $0$ and $X=n$ with probability $1$.